# How do I make a bar chart in the Data Explorer?

Tags: discussion, support, data-explorer

I've been wondering if there was a way to graph something in SEDE other than a line graph, because line graphs are boring. I figured out how to do a scatter plot, but it's still not as cool as a bar graph would be.

There's no built-in way to do this. What code would work to emulate a bar graph?

(Note: I'm self-answering with my own solution. I found a trick which, although flawed, gives cool looking results. I just wanted to share with everyone so that you can make cool graphs too.)

Comment: FWIW, adding more powerful graphing support is on the todo list, so I'd be interested in hearing different use cases and suggested ways of picking options

Comment: @TimStone Is there a place where they announced that? (I didn't see anything when I searched earlier...)

Comment: @PatrickHofman I was pretty sure of that. I was just curious if there's a list of what they plan to add. (I made at least two suggestions on how they could improve it, one being zoomable graphs, and the other being a way to hide the label.)

Comment: @PatrickHofman Unfortunately, no. Tim is the primary maintainer for the Data Explorer, though.

Comment: @PatrickHofman There's no hiring/employment involved.

Comment: So what is the relationship of him with SE and SEDE?

Comment: @PatrickHofman He does a lot of work on SEDE (it's just an [open source project](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer)) and we really really appreciate it.

Comment: @AdamLear Who programmed the UI for the website? Is it part of that project?

Comment: @Laurel Yeah, the UI is part of it. As for who wrote it... it's been a joint effort over many years. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution that creates a bar graph like this:

[image: Bar Graph]

(The data is from Super User.)

I think it's really cool, and it's a good way to present visual information from searches. It's *technically* just a really cool version of a scatter plot, because each dot is a point.

You can remove the label by hacking the HTML. Simply delete `<div class="legend">` (and all the HTML inside that node).

This is the [code](https://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/626450/recommendation-bar-graph#graph) I used (it finds and sorts possible recommendation questions):

```sql
Select top 500
(case 
    when lower(title) like '%open source%' then 0
    when lower(title) like '%recommend%'   then 1    
    when lower(title) like '%free%'        then 2
    when lower(title) like '%good%'        then 2
    when lower(title) like '%best%'        then 2
    when lower(title) like '%better%'      then 2
    when lower(title) like '%any%'         then 2
    when lower(title) like '%what%should%' then 3
    when lower(title) like '%which%should%'then 3
    when lower(title) like '%is there%'    then 3
    when lower(title) like '%looking for%' then 4
    else 5 end
), 
left(title,25) --as [Post Link]

,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (

  PARTITION BY(case 
      when lower(title) like '%open source%' then 0
      when lower(title) like '%recommend%'   then 1    
      when lower(title) like '%free%'        then 2
      when lower(title) like '%good%'        then 2
      when lower(title) like '%best%'        then 2
      when lower(title) like '%better%'      then 2
      when lower(title) like '%any%'         then 2
      when lower(title) like '%what%should%' then 3
      when lower(title) like '%which%should%'then 3
      when lower(title) like '%is there%'    then 3
      when lower(title) like '%looking for%' then 4
      else 5 end
  )
  ORDER BY (case 
      when lower(title) like '%open source%' then 0
      when lower(title) like '%recommend%'   then 1    
      when lower(title) like '%free%'        then 2
      when lower(title) like '%good%'        then 2
      when lower(title) like '%best%'        then 2
      when lower(title) like '%better%'      then 2
      when lower(title) like '%any%'         then 2
      when lower(title) like '%what%should%' then 3
      when lower(title) like '%which%should%'then 3
      when lower(title) like '%is there%'    then 3
      when lower(title) like '%looking for%' then 4
      else 5 end
)) AS Number

from posts

where (title like '%library%'
   or title like '%tool%'
   or title like '%book%'
   or title like '%tutorial%')
and closeddate is null
and deletiondate is null
```

---

Note: This post has been updated with a more perfect bar graph method (although the code is more redundant now). [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZKEy.png) is the original graph and [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/revision/481553/610433/recommendation) is the original query.