# What chart types should SEDE support?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, graphs

In a comment on another post, [Tim Stone said this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278966/how-do-i-make-a-bar-chart-in-the-data-explorer#comment903775_278966):

> FWIW, adding more powerful graphing support is on the todo list, so I'd be interested in hearing different use cases and suggested ways of picking options

So here it is: what type of chart would you love to see in SEDE to generate your very cool and just as useful charts?

Answer (score 6):

Well, obviously bar graphs. It was [my quest for SEDE bar graphs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/278967/323179) that started this discussion, after all.

I think that we also really need to have better a better interface for graphing. As it is, I am limited to three columns in my `SELECT`, and the label always gets in my way (I would rather see the label in the hover tooltip instead). And I can barely see the data when the graph has outliers, so I want to be able to zoom in. (Note that I have already proposed all of these as separate feature requests, I may add links later.) But I do want to keep the ability to create and graph complex queries.

And maybe we should add pie graphs, too.

---

Here's my answer in graph form:

```
          █
          █
          █
          █
  █       █
  █       █
  █       █
  █   █   █
  █   █   █
--+---+---+----
  |   |   `-- Better interface
  |   `------ Pie charts
  `---------- Bar graphs
```

Comment: [Not pie charts](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2009/04/pie-charts-are-bad/).