# Does SEDE has some built-in data visualization tools?

Tags: support, data-explorer

Exploring data visually might help users get a whole view quickly, does SEDE has some basic built-in data visualization tools?

Comment: Only simple line graphs: https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsede%5D+graph+is%3Aq which is also explained in the SEDE help: https://data.stackexchange.com/help#graphing

Comment: I forgot the awesome bar-graph that Laurel made: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278966/how-do-i-make-a-bar-chart-in-the-data-explorer